# giving a lower clock rate to circuit in system generator

Tags: fpga, clock, clock-speed, xilinx-system-generator

I want to give a lower clock rate to my circuit in System Generator. Can any one help me in this manner?

Comment: One can't with the information given.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have a circuit which I want to set a FIFO at the output, but I want to give to FIFO a clock which is faster than the clock of the circuit. I decided to give the clock to FIFO and a lower clock to the circuit. I need help for this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I suggest you use a simple counter circuit. This will allow you to divide your clock by powers of 2.

Comment: can you give me the circuit for this circuit?

Comment: Gladly: http://aviationandaccessories.tpub.com/TM-55-4920-401-13P/img/TM-55-4920-401-13P_53_1.jpg

Comment: That doesn't help? I didn't think it would. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop until the end of the page until you understand it. Then you will be a master of basic digital logic.

Answer (score 0):

For many /2 clocks get a 4020 chip, which is very common.

[image]